# iMac latest IOX, Word for Mac 2011

Tags: microsoft-word

I am creating a template word document with custom styles etc.. Section 1, Sub-section 1.1, sub-section 1.1.1 etc. Problem is Each section is defaulting to the next page. I do not have any page or section breaks included nor any paragraph spacing. Just allot of white. Help....

Comment: Seems like my document is defaulting to "Next Page" page break and I can't turn it off or default to "Continuous"

Answer (score 0):

I understand that each section level has its own style. It sounds like you might have **Page break before** checked in the base style definition.

[image: location of Page break before option]